# Swift Core Data many-to-many doesn't save

Tags: swift, xcode, core-data, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship for buddy-conversation. I try to save a conversation for a buddy like this:

```
let conversations = buddy.valueForKeyPath("conversations") as? NSMutableSet
            conversations?.addObject(newConversation)
CoreData.sharedInstance.saveContext()
```

My log tells me, the buddy has a conversation, but the next time i I run the App, the buddy doesn't have a conversation an it creates a new one.

I tried this

```
@NSManaged func addConversationObject(conversation: Conversation)
```

but I get an error every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm interpreting this as being based on two different entities, buddies and conversations, where a buddy can be in multiple conversations and each conversation can have multiple buddies participating.  If so, if the conversation is a new one, you'd create the record for it and link the buddy through whatever property you've defined to link them (let's say a buddy could be participatingIn a conversation).  then, to create the conversation and link the buddy (say buddy1) you'd use:

```
guard let newConversation = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "Conversation", into: context) as? Conversation else
{...damage control for the CoreData failure...}

buddy1.participatingIn = newConversation
```

At that point, you'd also want to set whatever other values you have in the Conversation record.  On the other hand, if you're adding buddy1 to an existing conversation, you'd have or retrieve that conversation (say as conversation1) and link buddy1 in with:

```
buddy1.participatingIn = conversation1
```

I hope that fits your design / helps.

Comment: I created a record for the new conversation. And it's saved.
I'm doing it like this:

`if buddy?.conversations?.count == 0 {
            startNewConversationWithBuddies(buddies: [buddy!])
        }`



startNewConversation:
`let newConversation  = Conversation.createNewConversation(name: conversationName)

        
        for buddy in buddies {
            let conversations = buddy.valueForKeyPath("conversations") as? NSMutableSet
            conversations?.addObject(newConversation)
CoreData.sharedInstance.saveContext()`

Comment: Are you sure about the addObject() function?  I'm used to having the NSManagedObject subClasses generated pick up the relationship name as in this example:  

extension WaypointSourceType {
  '@nonobjc class func fetchRequest()...
         …Attributes…
    '@NSManaged var describesSource: NSSet?
}

// MARK: Generated accessors for describesSource
extension WaypointSourceType {

    '@objc(addDescribesSourceObject:)
    '@NSManaged func addToDescribesSource(_ value: Waypoint)
…

So in this case the call would be:

waypointSource?.addToDescribesSource(newWaypointSource)

Comment: Xcode didn't generate the extension... with the new update Xcode generates the extension too. It's working fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad it's working, the transition to Xcode 8 was a challenge at times but atlas it's over now...